# ScrollView showing extra space while showing fragment

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have an issue where I am showing a fragment in a     scrollview,but the thing is that the scrillview always shows extra space(or I think complete fragment page) while the data is only half page. How can I make scrollview not showing the whole fragment page and only the text part.I though of making the parent LinareLayout wrap in fragment activity but doesn't work for me.

The activity xml where inside a scrolview a LinearLayout is put and later I replace it with a fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.1"
    android:background="#FF52caf7"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="backtoschedule"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Schedule Order"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txtm" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="7.9"
    android:background="@drawable/pbackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10.05">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5.975"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/defaultsofragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.025"
        android:background="#ffd1d1d1" />

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">


            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Instruction"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtss" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="You agree with terms and conditions"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts2" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center|left"

                android:text="Use Coupon"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtss" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/couponcode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="coupon code"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textColorHint="#FFABABAB"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtss" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.025"
        android:background="#ffd1d1d1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/img"></LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#ff57caf2"
        android:onClick="orderconfirm"
        android:text="Confirm Order"
        android:textColor="#fff0f0f0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txtss" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

 ////////////////////////////////////////
 The fragment activity xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/pbackground"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:stretchColumns="*">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:padding="3dip"


                android:text="ORDER DETAILS"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtss" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Delivery Type"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dtype"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Loading..."
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Schedule Pickup"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:gravity="left"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spdate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Loading..."
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sptime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Loading..."
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Schedule DropOff"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:gravity="left"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sddate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Loading..."
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sdtime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Loading..."
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />


        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:padding="3dip"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtss" />


        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left">


            <TextView


                android:id="@+id/caddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="3dip"

                android:scrollbars="vertical"

                android:text="Shanti Niketanjnkwejrkjwoperjposdasdasdasdasdasdasdwejprjwpoe,Lucknow,22-44-33"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txts" />


        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not getting what you are asking for, Do you want to show only the screen of text in scrollView??? but what about the rest of the screen what should it show then???

Comment: I have tried using match_parent for height in fragment. Now in fragment activity text is showing on complete screen but after replacement where fragment really shows in scrollbar it again becomes half  and half scroll goes blank.

Answer (score 1):

use this attribute inside Scrollview..

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: i have tried using fillViewport,but still showing me half blank scrolling.It is showing me complete fragment activity page and not just the wrap one. I have also put height wrap_parent wjere necessary